# APNS Distribution Profile

Tags: ios4, distribution, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

Hello good morning everyone, i have an iphone app which is still in development phase however i will be sending this to some beta testers using Distribution Provisioning.

1. Do i need to change the server URL from ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 to this ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196 ?

   1. How to configure the new Distribution provisioning profile?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 is for Debug/Release Applications.
ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196 is for AdHoc/Distribution Applications.

Comment: I have tried the URL above , i got this working for debug release :
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
but this doesnot work for Adhoc/Distribution :

ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196

Any help.. Many thanks :)

Comment: ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196 is not for push notification.

Comment: Hello yes sorry i have just tried it : so here :

ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

And it works :) Thanks.